# SQL Filestream Access Denied

Tags: sql, connection-string, filestream, access-denied

I'm attempting to implement BLOB Filestream for uploading and downloading files to the SQL database. Problem is I get Access is Denied error when I attempt to wright to the file. I'm using this as the connection string.

`<add name="connectionname" connectionString="Data Source=lceinforme;Initial Catalog=DEVDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;Max Pool Size=5000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

From what I've looked up and understand is that I can't use this approach? I keep reading using Integrated Security, but I don't think I can connect that way. This has me stumped.

Comment: What access is being denied? Access to the database, or access to the file being written to?

Comment: To the file being written to. I'm successful in creating the file ID and folder as far as I can tell. It's just writing to the folder is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is SQL Server 2008, then I believe that you have to use a Trusted Connection in order for Filestream to work.  You are specifying a Username and Password in your connection string, which means that you are using a SQL Login, and not a Trusted Connection.

If this is a later version of SQL Server, then ... (sorry got interrupted)
  ... it depends on the SQL Server settings.

Yes, Windows/AD Impersonation should work (however, SQL Server Impersonation probably will not).

Comment: No, it's a 2008 R2 server if I'm not mistaken. Or it might just be 2008, not 100% sure.

Comment: That's the thing, we're trying to limit this to a single SQL login connection, but I'll double check that.