# How to use filestream when Web Server and Database server does not reside on same domain

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, filestream

We have an MVC 5 application used for serving images and documents settled on Web-server, and File-stream database settled on SQL Server. SQL Server is in domain network, but MVC application is not.

What kind of connection string we need to use for connecting to SQL Server, and which IIS account we need to use to connect MVC application to SQL Server?

Comment: "File-stream database settled on SQL Server" do you mean you file-streamed blob items saved in SQL tables?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that web app and sql database are on different servers and domains.

Comment: should not be any difference in approaches. Just different connection string to your DB, pointing to SQL Server machine, rather than localhost.

Comment: SQL Server is installed on Server 1 and hosts a FILESTREAM-enabled database. Web Application is configured on Server 2. The web application connects to SQL Server. The problem is those two servers are not in the same domain, and in this case we need to use Windows authentication to connect to database.

Comment: You'll need to switch to non-win authentication and create SQL user with password.

Comment: SQL user doesn't have access rights to file system on sql server, because FILESTREAM uses file system.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of connection string we need to use for connecting to SQL
>   Server?

As both Application server and SQL Server are not in same domains. You can use use SQL Authentication for connection. So first create a SQL Login for SQL Server and then use its Username and password in the connectionstring -

```
Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; User Id=UserName; Password=UserPassword;
```

If you need to use Domain Account to connect to SQL Server, then you need to join Web Server to the Domain and then you can use SSPI Trusted authenitcation -

```
Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

To be more specific when it comes to User delegation betweeb Servers, you need to use [Kerberos Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319723)

For SQL Server 2008 with SQL FileStreamsSQL, [connectionstring must be trusted one. And SQL Server greater than 2008, then it depends on SQL Server settings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981759/sql-filestream-access-denied)

Comment: You can't use SQL authentication for remote connection to FileStream database. That is the problem. You need to use integrated security, but then two servers need to be in the same domain, which is not our case.

Comment: Is there a way not to join two servers in the same domain, and still use filestream access?